# ngOptions with array of objects does not set the first value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have an array of objects with the following format:

```
[
  {key: 'SC', name: 'Santa Catarina'},
  {key: 'SP', name: 'São Paulo'},
  {key: 'RJ', name: 'Rio de Janeiro'}
]
```

And I want to use `select` and `ng-options` to show those values:

```
<select ng-model="vm.state"
    ng-options="state.name for state in vm.states">
</select>
```

However, if `vm.state` already has a value, the select does not start with it selected. Does anyone know how to make it happen?

[Fiddle demonstrating the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/zyoon5d4/)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `track by` in this case, where you are retrieving selected object from some ajax call.

```
<select ng-model="vm.state"
      ng-options="state.name for state in vm.states track by state.key">
</select>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2ek9as1/)

> **NOTE:** `track by` will not work if you are using `select as` in `ng-options` expression.`

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: @tpsilva glad to know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have to set it yourself, something like

```
$scope.states=[...]
$scope.state=$scope.states[0]
```

Comment: I would have to iterate to find the index of the object I want.  Isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to set it your self because vm.state will get the value from your vm.states. You can use ng-init to set it.

```
  <select ng-model="vm.state"
        ng-options="state.name for state in vm.states" ng-init="vm.state = $scope.states[0]">
    </select>
```

Comment: The value is retrieved from a service, I don't know the index without iterating. And thats what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: you can filter your states and get the index in and set index.

vm.states.filter(function(state, index, self){
 if(valueFromService == state){
vm.state = self[index];
}
})